# Prove $\#A \leq \#B \implies \#P(A) \leq \#P(B)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am having trouble properly constructing a function that goes from $P(A) \rightarrow P(B)$. Furthermore I have to show that it is injective.

$\#A \leq \#B \iff$ There exists an injection $m:A \rightarrow B$.

$m(x) \in B$.

Let's call the function from $P(A)$ to $P(B)$, $M$.

- $M(X) = \{m(a) | a \in X\}$, where $X \subseteq A$.

How can I prove this is an injection, moreover, how can I show this while using my hypothesis?

---

$M(X_1) = M(X_2)$

$M(X_1) = \{m(a) | a \in X_1\}$

$M(X_2) = \{m(a) | a \in X_2\}$

$\implies \{m(a) | a \in X_1\} = \{m(a) | a \in X_2\}$.

$m(a_1) = m(a_2) \implies a_1 = a_2$ since $m(a)$ is injective,

so it follows that $a \in X_1 = a \in X_2$.

$\implies X_1 = X_2$.

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what are you stuck on? Just write down the definition of injectivity and show that your function $F$ satisfies it.

Comment: I'll post an update of what I have thus far.

Comment: There's a "$f$" that pops out a couple of times (one in the title and one where I'd expect "$m$"). Is it important or is it a typo?

Comment: Definitely a typo, sorry. Using M on my assignment but I know f is more commonly used so I started with it here.

Comment: You're great up until "so it follows that $a \in X_1 = a \in X_2$." First, you mean so it follows that $a \in X_1 \iff a \in X_2$. Second, you should prove this assertion, not just assert it. (Start by assuming $a \in X_1$, and show that $a \in X_2$; and vice versa.)